# Remote Data Annotation not working ASP.NET mvc 4

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, data-annotations

I have a serious problem when using [Remote] Attribute. So here is my code :

I Have included all the Jquery Libraries needed for Remote Validation :

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </head>
```

Also here is my Code on the Domain class Wich is called Agence :

```
public class Agence
    {   
        #region Properties

        [Key]
        [Column("num_siret")]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Numéro Siret")]
        [Remote("ValidateNumSiretNumberDigits", "RemoteValidation")]
        public long NumSiret { get; set; }
        . . . . . . . 
}
```

Here is my Controller RemoteValidation :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public class RemoteValidationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Admin/RemoteValidation/

        public ActionResult ValidateNumSiretNumberDigits(long numSiret)
        {
            string s = numSiret.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (s.Equals('0'))
                    s.Remove(i);
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return Json(s.Count()==15, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the validation does't work, and when I press the validation buttom nothing happens ! Even when I set the validation always to true in the return parameter of JSon nothing happens. I should also tell you that the validation is called from a Creation Page on an Admin Area .I suspect that the problem is the JQuery plugins that I've included, because sincerely I didn't work very much with JQuery. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `jquery.validate.js` plugin and also the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script to make the MVC client side validation work.

If you've created a standard MVC4 there is already a bundle with these scripts preconfigured: `"~/bundles/jqueryval"`

So you just need to remove the two `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com...` line (anyway it makes no sense to include both the debug and the min version) and replace it with following `Scripts.Render` call:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: How do you use the `public long NumSiret` in your view? How is the generated html look like for that field?

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumSiret)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumSiret)

Comment: should I put both @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
         and @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") in the master page ?

Comment: Yes, you can put them in the _Layout.cshtml. Is your `@Html.EditorFor` inside in a `Html.BeginFrom` block? Is your view a partial and are you loading it with AJAX? It would be nice if you would post the generated html of the NumSiret field (right click in browser and view source)...

Comment: And also make sure that the above mentioned scripts jquery.validate.js plugin and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js are rendered in the HTML and also that your browser was able to load them.

Comment: Sorry it was too long so I have to make it an answer not a comment, it is below

Comment: Thank you I found the problem :) It was a stupis freaky idea to put my validation Controller outside the area, so when the validation is called it will think that the validation controller is in the current area, when I have put it into the Admin Area everything worked fine :) Thank you the view source code, I learning from you @nemesv ;)